# Binding HyperLinks to GridView using AutoGenerateColumns

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink, datatable

I have a DataTable which has columns that are generated dynamically at runtime. This DataTable is bound to a GridView that has AutoGenerateColumns set to true. I've run into a problem with this since some of the data in the DataTable are HyperLink objects, so instead of displaying the actual link in the table, it displays "System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink".

Normally, I would just use a HyperLinkField in my GridView, but since the GridView's columns are generated automatically, I'm not sure how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you storing the Hyperlink in the Datatable and not only the Link?

Comment: @Tim: I assume by link you mean the plain text? I can store it either way, but if I store just the link, how do I render it as an HTML link in the GridView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new column dynamically, you'll just have to hide the automatically generated columns also.

For this solution you can either store the hyperlink in 2 columns - 1 for the link and 1 for the text you want displayed, or if you want something generic displayed (like 'Click Here') you can just store the link (eg "http://example.com.au/Default.aspx").

```
protected void GridView1_RowBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        //add new header
        TableCell tc = new TableCell();
        tc.Text = "Groovy Link";
        e.Row.Cells.Add(tc);
        //hide original column that has been autobound - skip column we just added
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            BoundField field = (BoundField)((DataControlFieldCell)e.Row.Cells[i]).ContainingField;
            if (field.DataField == "AutoGeneratedColumnName")
                field.Visible = false;
        }
    }
    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //create new tablecell
        TableCell tc = new TableCell();
        //do a check to see if the data is stored as a hyperlink in DB
        if (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "AutoGeneratedColumnName").ToString().StartsWith("<a") == true)
        {
            //create hyperlink
            HyperLink hyp = new HyperLink();
            hyp.NavigateUrl = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "AutoGeneratedColumnName").ToString();
            hyp.Text = "click here";
            tc.Controls.Add(hyp);
        }
        else
        {
            //just text
            tc.Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "AutoGeneratedColumnName").ToString()
        }
        //add tablecell to row
        e.Row.Cells.Add(tc);
        //hide original column that has been autobound
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            BoundField field = (BoundField)((DataControlFieldCell)e.Row.Cells[i]).ContainingField;
            if (field.DataField == "AutoGeneratedColumnName")
                field.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem I have is that, depending on the data, the item may either be a HyperLink or just a string.

Comment: @Tyler: Do you want to display the string items as hyperlinks?

Comment: @JumpingJezza: no, some of the items are links and some are not.

Comment: @Tyler: So how do you differentiate between them? Do you have any control over the data?

Comment: @JumpingJezza: I have complete control over the data.

Comment: @Tyler: So is it possible to only store links in that DB column? Can you edit your question to provide some example data?

Comment: @JumpingJezza: what I want is a column in the GridView that displays either a link or just plain text depending on what the value from the DataTable is. I am able to determine which values are links and which aren't, and I'm able to completely build the URL. I just don't know how to have a column that displays both or what the alternatives are.